# How to merge 2 applications using their own Gruntfile.js and their having their own package.json

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have two differents apps using a gruntfile.js and a package.json and when i launch locally my second app (providing only 1 functionnality, thats why i trying to merge it with the other), this works, but when i try to works the functionnality by merging the second app in the principal app, it says that modules are missing.

My principal app is the BPMN editor from: https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js

And the second app is the BPMN-diffing from: https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js-diffing

My BPMN_editor's Gruntfile is minifying BPMN_editor's .js files, then i tried to do the same for BPMN diffing's js files. but nothing is working, my node server wont run normally (while hes working without this BPMN diffing).

I dont understand how to use the bpmn diffing, should i make an npm install to install all dependencies of bpmn diffing, and then make an npm install of the bpmn editor to install dependencies ? or should i merge the Gruntfiles and the package.json files ?

Thanks a lot

Fantemis

Answer (score 0):

If they are based upon two differrent configurations, I would prefer using a load balancer or a reverse proxy to load them on the server. Merging the projects takes a little more insights from you and a little effort. The effort always depends on the setup. I would give you a little tip, but **I am not seeing a Gruntfile in your main principle repository**.

- [A little insight into "Reverse Proxy vs. Load Balancer"](https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/reverse-proxy-vs-load-balancer/)
- [What is the difference between Reverse Proxy and Load Balancers](https://serverfault.com/questions/127021/what-is-the-difference-between-load-balancer-and-reverse-proxy)

---

**Alternative 1 (preferred):**

You could however create a small node.js server, which is handling the serving of those two applications, like the following:

```
- bpmn_root
|- principal
|- diffing
```

Afterwards you just need to write a little script, that is building both things on the server you want it to be deployed, and then you just need to do `node SCRIPT_NAME.js`.

[Further reading](https://forums.docker.com/t/multiple-applications-in-a-single-container/54772/2), and [another post about this](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/).

---

**Alternative 2:**

You can use Docker. I am not very aware of how to use Docker to power such thing, but it is "as simple as" creating an Nginx configuration, which is doing the reverse proxy stuff for you.

---

**Alternative 3:**

Using the load balancer, which is handling the reverse proxy automatically. This is also a little more complex and needs some more learning to do. You can find plenty of tutorials on this however on the internet.